# Trying to place javascript statements in an array

Tags: javascript

I have the line `document.getElementById('slot2').src ="snail.gif";` in my code and it works to change the img element to the appropriate gif.

However I also have an array called slots of three elements each of which is `document.getElementById('slotN')` or 1 2 and 3 in place of N.

When I use `slots[2].src ="snail.gif";` in a function it fails to do anything.

I know it has to do with converting the string of the statement into a statement but trying to use eval() doesn't seem to work either.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be with the fact that arrays are 0-indexed. `slots[2]` is actually the **third** element in the array. If you only have two elements, they will be `slots[0]` and `slots[1]`. Trying to set the src of `slots[2]` will not work because that doesn't exist.

You could make an array of your images:

```
myImages = ["img1.gif", "another.gif"]
```

And then reference slotN like below:

```
document.getElementById("slot" + n).src = myImages[n];
```

Make sure your "slotN" elements start from 0 (or add 1).

Comment: Thanks Sachleen I worked this out by setting a variable to be equal to the element of the array which contained the code and then used eval() on the variable